# win10 IoT FileOutputNodeAsync can't use mediaEncodingProfile

Tags: c#, audio-recording, windows-10-iot-core

I want to use an AudioGraph to record from a microphone to the disk.  The code works fine on my PC (x86) when I run it on the Raspberry PI this call fails

```
CreateAudioFileOutputNodeResult result = await audioGraph.CreateFileOutputNodeAsync(file,mediaEncodingProfile);
```

always retuning an 'Unknown failure,'.

If I use the same call without specifying an encoding profile (like below) it works but the file it creates cannot be played back (no idea what format this is. The file seems to start with RIFF which I think is a .wav file), but nothing seems to be able to play the created file back :(

```
CreateAudioFileOutputNodeResult result = await audioGraph.CreateFileOutputNodeAsync(file);
```

So I am really confused, what is the default file format if no media encoder is provided, why can't i use mp3,wav etc.. for saving files (does IoT not have the encoders), it will play the files back.

Any ideas how I can play back the file that is saved in whatever the default file format is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 10 and cannot speak to any other platform. I have run into the same failure encoding profile issue on W10. Here's what I've observed:

Encoding Profiles:

1. null - appears to default to CreateWav() - fails everywhere except VLC
2. CreateAvi - doesn't work anywhere
3. CreateM4A - doesn't work anywhere
4. CreateMp3 - best - works well, no clipping of end
5. CreateWma - works but clips last few seconds
6. CreateWmv - works but clips last few seconds
7. CreateWav - same as null above

My conclusion, so far, is that W10 AudioGraph has lots of issues (clips last few seconds, invalid header). For CreateWav, I suspect the issues are due to bogus close file logic. I don't think there's an issue with my code because three encoding profiles are work (mostly).

The inability to get the default (wav) working is a pretty bad. Anyone?

Edit - 19-Dec-2015 - I've found the issue with my code and perhaps the OP. I needed to use a finalization API call to close the output (wav) file. Apparently the call makes a difference for some file formats and not others.

Stop event should have this code

```
graph.Stop();
Windows.Media.Transcoding.TranscodeFailureReason finalizeResult = await fileOutputNode.FinalizeAsync();
  if (finalizeResult != TranscodeFailureReason.None)
  {
    // error - error message in finalizeResult.ToString()
    return;
  }
```